# Visual Studio Color Variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a form with many controls(500+) 
How can I use a variable name in the designer so that I can change the colour once and update all controls on the designer in 1 go?

Surely I don't need to write it in the code for every control?

Also if I was creating a colour theme  chooser , it would need to use this same idea.

I had a good look online but nothing shows up for using variables in the designer properties?

Comment: you can select multiple controls then change any properties they share all at once.  if they are many types of controls, you might need to do all the buttons, then all the labels etc

Comment: Or you could try to write your own theme manager for the designer to manage the color of the controls (as can be seen in Krypton, DotNetBar, ComponentOne, Telerik, etc).

Comment: So there is no way to have the designer parse a variable, from a variable in the my.settings or similar ?   or where i can add custom colors on the pallet , it cant be set to use  color x and then change the value of x?  hmm this really sucks

Comment: the designer doesnt use variables (or Settings) - do you want to do this in code or in the designer?

Comment: like i said i have 100's of controls ,  i cant do it in the code , as i would have to relist every object.  The designer writes the layout to a file, it could possible read a variable so i assume its not set to do that, but is there anyway to add a colourname to the system colours so that i can change the actual color of the colorname and have all the object update instantly.  So your saying if someone wants to do color themes , they must update the color of every object and not just change the color itself?? what a waste of memory

Comment: you can use a For Each loop to iterate the controls and change to color in 5 lines of code. VS also has a nice Search and Replace facility.  are you trying to do something like themes?

Comment: they are all different colours , this isnt practical at all. i guess this is just a poor GUI Designer for this type of project,  i will have to take the designer output file once finished with the layout and replace all the colours with variables , thanks!

Comment: that probably wont work like you think.  if you change the value of BackColor1, it wont 'update all the objects instantly'...and everytime VS saves the file it will overwrite your changes.

Comment: i have no problem in refreshing the form :)  i just need a way to update the colours with out a huge list of variables , the project is already pushing  winforms to the limits!

Comment: I've wrote my own replace function similar to changing the designer file, well for other controls to be replaced. But this is similar. You could write your own replace function that would go through the designer and change what you would need. The project must be closed before doing so...

Comment: On another note, you can't use a variables as you intended and others have mentioned. Either change them manually or process the designer yourself. If you would have created your own controls using inheritace, you could have used your own property that would make this possible.

Comment: If you really need an example please let me know...

Comment: i have used variables in the designer file in the past to work out widths and heights... it seemed to work fine as long as i never opened the designer again , because it just rewrote the file again based on the current form in the designer.

Comment: sorry , not variables,   i used the heights of other objects as a reference to scale other items,   i guess i cant define a var before this file is read?

Comment: No, not only that but it needs to recompile and when it does, BAM your at the beginning again.

Answer (score -2):

You can set a variable at run time then pick the controls you want to change.

```
Dim mycolor as Color = Color.Red
For each txt as TextBox in Me.Controls
txt.BackColor = mycolor
Next
```

Then you change them the same way or change what mycolor is(assuming its a top level variable)

Comment: the controls collection can contain more than just textboxes.  the correct code to iterate just TBs would be: `For Each t As TextBox In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()`

Comment: correct, mine would only work on the textbox but throw an exception for anything else, was only an example :)

Comment: 100's of controls and different colors?? really?    i know this , im not talking about this , im talking about the designer itself